# Asyncio can't close sessions

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I wrote telegram-bot and that's how my main.py file looks like, I need to run another bot simultaneously but it fails with this mistake:

```
import asyncio
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage

import config
from handlers import router


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())
    dp.include_router(router)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

after I try to run it in another project I get

```
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramUnauthorizedError: Telegram server says Unauthorized
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x105c55130>
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x105c66be0>, 0.718218208)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x105c55040>
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Every bot needs its own token.  Did you get a second token?

Comment: Yes, BOT_TOKEN is different for the second project